# symfony2 http caching lose custom response header

Tags: rest, symfony, caching, http-headers, cors

I've implemented a REST API with Symfony 2 and the fos REST bundle. I also use the nelmio CORS bundle to manage the CORS headers on responses.

Everything works fine.

Now, I've implemented [HTTP caching](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/http_cache.html) on one of my REST API endpoint (a collection of entities from the database that is changed very rarely).

HTTP caching works fine but the CORS headers on the response of this REST endpoint are all lost, even if I try to set them manually:

```
$response = $this->handleView($this->view($ret, 200));

$response->setPublic();
$response->setMaxAge(21600);
$response->setSharedMaxAge(21600);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

return $response;
```

Is it possible to keep the CORS headers when using HTTP caching and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, HTTP caching is caching the headers too. And if I access my API directly before accessing it from sub2.domain.com, it won't be allowed as the response was not cached with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (NelmioCors set it dynamically depending from where you access the app).